# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException during JSF validation

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf

I have problem with my project which uses Spring, Hibernate and JSF.

I have such view:

**addAcInsuranceProduct.xhtml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="./../../template/mainTemplate.xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:form="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components">

    <ui:define name="content">        
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">    
               <p:outputLabel value="AC insurance range"/>
                <p:selectManyCheckbox id="range" layout="grid" columns="1" styleClass="defaultSelect" 
                                      value="#{addAcInsuranceProductMB.product.range}">
                </p:selectManyCheckbox>
                <h:column/>

                <p:commandButton id="testBtn" value="Test"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

and classes:

**AddAcInsuranceProductMB.java**:

```
(...)
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AddAcInsuranceProductMB extends AddProductMB{

public AddAcInsuranceProductMB() {
    product = new AcInsuranceProduct();
}

public AcInsuranceProduct getProduct() {
    return (AcInsuranceProduct) product;
}

}
```

**AddProductMB.java**:

```
(...)

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AddProductMB implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{insuranceService}")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    IInsuranceService service;

    @Getter
    Integer ID;

    Product product;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            ID = Integer.valueOf(Ctx.getParam("ID")); //Ctx is helper class and it works fine
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            ID = null;
        }

        if (ID != null) {
            product = service.getProductById(ID); //in my test case it is AcInsuranceProduct, code below
        }
    }
```

**AcInsuranceProduct.java**:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "ins_ac_product")
public class AcInsuranceProduct extends Product { //Product has field Integer id with getter and setter

    (...)
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "ins_ac_product_range", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "productId"))
    @Column(name = "rangeId")
    @Enumerated(javax.persistence.EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private List<AcInsuranceRange> range;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return super.equals(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }
```

**InsuranceService.java**:

```
(...)
@Service
public class InsuranceService implements IInsuranceService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "productDao")
    private IGenericDao<Product> productDao;

    @Override
    public Product getProductById(Integer ID) {
        return productDao.findById(ID);
    }

}
```

**GenericDao.java**:

```
public class GenericDao<E> implements IGenericDao<E> {

    @Getter @Setter
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private final Class<E> type;

    public static final int ASC = 0;
    public static final int DESC = 1;

    public GenericDao(Class<E> type) {
        this.type=type;
    }

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public E findById(Serializable id) {
        return (E) getSession().get(type, id);
    }

}
```

Now when I click on Test button I get such exception:

```
WARNUNG: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.write(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.add(PersistentBag.java:291)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValuesForModel(MenuRenderer.java:381)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValue(MenuRenderer.java:128)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:314)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectmanycheckbox.SelectManyCheckboxRenderer.getConvertedValue(SelectManyCheckboxRenderer.java:39)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1046)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:976)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.efsf.eurobroker.util.filter.ConnectionFilter.doFilter(ConnectionFilter.java:15)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But if I add immediate="true" to button to skip validation process everything is working fine.

On the other hand when I have full form (I skipped many components here to simplify) I see that product in **init()** method from **AddProductMB** class is correct object with correct data loaded from database. And I don't have any problems when I don't try to get product from database in above method. Without that all is fine.

How can I get rid of this exception?

Comment: Balus thx for format my exceptions and sorry that I didn't put them into code block

Comment: It's indeed duplicate, sorry then. I didn't find it by myself.